# Pushing UITableViewCell out of view breaks constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I've created some prototype cells to display my data in a `UITableView`. The prototype cell I'm currently using has

- Two labels for team names
- Two images (logos) for each team
- A `UIView` with a grey background, containing:

  - Two labels for each team's score
  - A label with a colon for score separation

After some initial issues with placing constraints in the Interface Builder I have managed to create (presumably) conflict-free layout constraints to keep everything in place. Everything worked just as expected in the simulator (iPhone 5), but as soon as I load it to my physical iPhone 5 something's breaking.

At first everything looks okay (left image). Once I swipe one of the `TableViewCell`s outside the view (second image), some of the constraints break, hiding the outer two labels and changing the cell height (third image). -- This doesn't happen when I'm running the app in the simulator.

This happens for every of the cells, once it's pushed outside the visible view.

[image: Demo of the constraint break]

These are the warnings I get in my console:

```
2015-03-11 14:44:44.282 MSUapp[1280:942149] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
        Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x155f5170 H:[UIView:0x155f3fe0(50)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x155f5580 UIImageView:0x155f54d0.width == UIImageView:0x155f54d0.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x155f5bf0 UILabel:0x155f5820'1. FC K\U00f6ln'.leading == UITableViewCellContentView:0x156ed850.leadingMargin - 7>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x155f5c50 H:[UILabel:0x155f5820'1. FC K\U00f6ln']-(15)-[UIImageView:0x155f54d0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x155f5cb0 UIView:0x155f3fe0.top == 0.4*UITableViewCellContentView:0x156ed850.centerYWithinMargins>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x155f5ce0 UIView:0x155f3fe0.bottom == 1.6*UITableViewCellContentView:0x156ed850.centerYWithinMargins>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x155f5d10 H:[UIImageView:0x155f54d0]-(5)-[UIView:0x155f3fe0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x155f5d40 UITableViewCellContentView:0x156ed850.centerX == UIView:0x155f3fe0.centerX>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x155f5d70 UIView:0x155f3fe0.height == UIImageView:0x155f54d0.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1552a0c0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x156ed850(320)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1552a090 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x156ed850(178.5)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x155f5580 UIImageView:0x155f54d0.width == UIImageView:0x155f54d0.height>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

This is a list of my constraints (I can't scale it up, so the end of the text is cropped):

[image: Constraints list]
[image: Storyboard]

The preview template represents the constraints, e.g. there's no warnings that anything is misplaced.

What can I do to prevent this from happening? Let me know if you need any additional information. Any help is appreciated!

**Update:**
I just changed a couple of the constraints and updated my previously tested iPhone 5 to iOS 8.3 beta. Now it's working on it. However, when I try it on an iPhone 6 (running iOS 8.1.3) the problem remains. Therefore it appears to be iOS version-specific. Are there any fixes for it?

Comment: the short answer - you have more constraints than needed, long answer, you`d probably need to show us the constraint list

Comment: Is a screenshot of the outline view and its constraints list sufficient?

Comment: i can give it a try :D

Comment: Edited the question. The right part of it is cropped, as I can't scale the outline view up any further :/ Thanks so far!

Comment: definitely you have to many constraints...because of the crop i cant see what with what is connected, i see 3 Centerer Y Alignement to centered box in the botom constraints box , what are you trying to center it to

Comment: I'm centering the 3 labels inside the center box to it, as well as the `UIImageViews`. If they were redundant or conflicting, wouldn't Xcode complain at runtime (or even already in the interface builder)?

Comment: well you are centering them  on Y and at the same time you are setting vertical space to them, thats first thing i saw, thats wrong, also why do you have 3 labels for representing score, wouldn't it be easier to have one with stringformat?

Comment: @Padarom can I ask you where you get the data from? Are you using OpenLigaDB.de? Or any other source? I would be happy if you could let me know, as I am looking for an alternative to OpenLigaDB.de which I use on a homepage.

Comment: @user1555112 The data is currently randomly generated. I work for a company that amongst other things develops sport "tracking" software for newspaper publishers. After using test data, we'll transition to using the data straight our software's database, which in turn has all kinds of different sources (depending on the customer), which might be manual entries, dpa, dfb, local leagues or OpenLigaDB as well

Comment: ok thanks! Goof look with your project!